# Is there a unique session id/ session key assigned to each shinyR session?

Tags: session, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a session id/ session key assigned to each shiny session (if deployed on a shiny server)? If yes, how do I access the info?
I have read the documentation [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/session.html) and looked online, however, could not really find the answer to my questions.

Any info would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I was looking into it and `session$token` worked for me

Best

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own. For example:

```
session.id <- reactive({ as.character(floor(runif(1)*1e20)) })
```

When `session.id()` is used for the first time, it will randomly generate a value, but since it does not contain any reactives it will never be invalidated and so the value will stay the same for the rest of the session.

Comment: brilliant @dk, sometimes simple solutions are the best.

Comment: however will there be any situation where two shiny apps would have the same token (represented by `session$token`)? e.g. can there be an anomolous situation if the second shiny app uses the first app memory due to same thread launch?
In that case the `session$token` would come handy.